# word meaning doing things arbitrarily without control at all

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about rebuilding my sleep schedule and looking for a word meaning doing things arbitrarily with no control whatsoever.

> I started __________, putting off sleep and waking up whenever I felt
>   like, except for mornings that I had work.

Is indulging or overindulging appropriate? What word would you use?

Comment: *haphazardly* means what you ask for, but doesn’t go in the sentence.

Comment: @jim On the contrary, [*haphazardly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haphazard) fits perfectly—and I was just about to turn that into an answer when the question was closed . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford - Yeah, I agree.  The reason I said it didn’t was because it significantly changes the direction that, I think, OP was headed in (based on the indulging/overindulging question).

Comment: @Jim Thanks so much. How would you use it in this case. Could you please give me an example with a rephrased structure?

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks so much. How would you use it in this case. Could you please give me an example with a rephrased structure?

Comment: @mfg Nothing would need to be rephrased. Simply take the sentence you already have in the question, and put *haphazardly* into the blank spot: *I started **haphazardly**, putting off sleep . . .* (I'm assuming it's obvious from other context *what* you started haphazardly. But the adverb describes *how* it was started.)

Comment: When I saw the title of your question, my first thought was to use “sleepwalking” metaphorically.  Given your actual context, that’s probably inappropriate.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, “haphazardly” does not fit in the sentence at all. Note the comma after the blank. It needs a verb, like “I started ***drifting***, putting off sleep …” Or you could say something like “I started ***acting*** haphazardly, …” or “I started ***behaving*** haphazardly, …”

Comment: @Scott It *has* a verb: ***started***. *Last month, I tried to build a house. **I started haphazardly,** putting off sleep . . .* There is nothing ungrammatical about that. Subject, verb, and adverb.

Comment: OK, maybe it works in that context.  We’re interpreting the OP differently.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd suggest **freewheel**:
>
> *freewheel* ... intransitive verb
>
> 2 : to move, live, or play freely or irresponsibly

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freewheel)]

I started freewheeling – putting off sleep and waking up whenever I felt like [it], except for mornings that I had work.

Answer (score 0):

Drifting or floundering would both work. 
Drifting would be better here because it fits in with the idea of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a word that fits well in the blank, but maybe:

> I abandoned discipline, putting off sleep and waking up whenever I felt like, except on mornings when I had to work.